# pyspark: find time diffs between rows with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am trying to calculate the sum of differences (in milliseconds) between values in some columns which depend on the value of another column.

More in details i have the following pyspark dataframe:

```
d = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(133515, "user1", 1562889600046, 'begin'), 
     (789456, "user2", 1562889600246, 'begin'),
     (789456, "user2", 1562889603046, 'end'),
     (712346, "user3", 1562889600046, 'begin'),
     (789456, "user4", 1562889700046, 'begin'),
     (133515, "user1", 1562889640046, 'end'),
     (712346, "user3", 1562889602046, 'end'),
     (789456, "user4", 1562889800046, 'end'),
     (789456, "user4", 1562889850046, 'begin'),
     (789456, "user4", 1562889903046, 'end'),
     (133515, "user1", 1562889645046, 'begin'),
     (133515, "user1", 1562889745046, 'end')

    ], ("ID", "user", "epoch", "ACTION"))
d.show()
```

I would expect the following output:

```
+------+-----+-----------+
|    ID| user|summed diff|
+------+-----+-----------+
|133515|user1|      50000|
|789456|user2|       2800|
|712346|user3|       2000|
|789456|user4|     153000|
+------+-----+-----------+
```

each value in the column `summed diff` is obtained by summing the differences in milliseconds between the "end" epoch and the last "begin" related to that specific user.

Can you please guide me on how to address this?

What if I want to group by i.e. day or hour of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

d_final = d.select(F.col("ID"), F.col("user"), F.when(F.col("ACTION") == lit("begin"), -F.col("epoch")).otherwise(F.col("epoch")).alias("epoch_temp")).groupBy(F.col("ID"), F.col("user")).agg(F.sum(F.col("epoch_temp")).alias("summed_diff"))
```

and the result:

```py
>>> d_final.show()
+------+-----+-----------+
|    ID| user|summed_diff|
+------+-----+-----------+
|789456|user4|     153000|
|712346|user3|       2000|
|133515|user1|     140000|
|789456|user2|       2800|
+------+-----+-----------+
```

---

**EDIT** - with udf to look cleaner

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

action_process = udf(lambda x: -1 if x=="begin" else 1, IntegerType())

d_final = d.select(F.col("ID"), F.col("user"), (action_process(F.col("ACTION")) * F.col("epoch")).alias("epoch_temp")).groupBy(F.col("ID"), F.col("user")).agg(F.sum(F.col("epoch_temp")).alias("summed_diff"))
```

and the result:

```py
>>> d_final.show()
+------+-----+-----------+
|    ID| user|summed_diff|
+------+-----+-----------+
|789456|user4|     153000|
|712346|user3|       2000|
|133515|user1|     140000|
|789456|user2|       2800|
+------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this using udf? just to make it less messy

Comment: yup, just added it.